# Keeping stream open with AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream

Tags: perl, twitter

I'm using [`AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aTwitter%3a%3aStream) to write a Twitter bot. I'm new to event-based programming, so I'm relying heavily on the docs.

Since this is a bot, I want the stream to keep going, unsupervised, when there's an error (such as a broken pipe, or a timeout error).

If I don't include an error handler at all, the entire program dies on error. Similarly, if I use an error handler like what's in the sample docs:

```
on_error => sub {
    my $error = shift;
    warn "Error: $error";
    $done->send;
},
```

The program dies. If I remove the "$done->send;" line, the stream is interrupted and the program hangs.

I've looked at the (sparse) docs for AE::T::S, and for AnyEvent, but I'm not sure what I need to do to keep things going. The stream can give me 5,000 events a minute, and I can't lose this on random network hiccups.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for anyone else using this:

I spoke to someone more knowledgeable about event-based stuff. Basically, each ::Stream object represents a single HTTP request to Twitter; when that request dies, that's the end of a stream. The on_error method is called at this point, so it's just giving you a place to say that the stream ended, for logging purposes or whatever. This method doesn't let you restart the stream.

If you want the bot to keep going, you have to create a new stream, either by having the OS restart the program, or just wrapping the entirety of the program in a while(1) {} loop.

Hope this helps someone else!